# MediaRecorder crashes on start() on Sprint Galaxy S3 when recording Audio

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

This code is working fine on a live app, but I just received an error report from a Sprint Galaxy S3 user.  It crashes on the last line with "Start Failed" on their particular device.  (The device is not rooted)

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MedieRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128);
mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96 * 1024);  //160 Kbps
mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
mRecorder.setAudioChannels(2); 
mRecorder.setOutputFile(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/myfile.caf");
mRecorder.prepare();
mRecorder.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that getFilePathAndName() actually returns a real path and location for saving the sound file. As you record using MediaRecorder, the sound bytes are concurrently being saved, so it must know where to save before recording. If it doesn't, it will crash on start(). To ensure that the file path exists, put this in getFilePathAndName():

```
String pathToExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File soundDir = new File(pathToExternalStorage + "/" + "YourAppName");   
//Build the directory structure, if needed.
soundDir.mkdirs();
```

Comment: Sorry about the typos, problems with pasting.  Can it be a new file name that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Absolutely. The directory must exist though before you set your file name, but you can create it using mkdirs(). Refer to the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html). And if you are planning on recording many sound files, I'd recommend using a date/time function for your file names so that you don't have issues with retrieval and playback. I personally use System.currentTimeMillis() in my app.

Comment: I replaced the getFilePathAndName call with the actual code inline.  I wonder if the .caf file extension is tripping up the Galaxy S3.

Comment: Ohhhh yeah caf files aren't supported by Android. It's not just your device, it's the OS. Supported audio formats will appear when you're filling in the parameter for setOutputFormat().

Comment: But if you implement my code and use a supported audio format, you should have no troubles recording.

Comment: How did it work out for you, bgolson? Did you fix it?

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I still have to get a test version out to my user with the Galaxy S3.  The app works fine for the rest of our Install base.  I'm going to try to record with a standard file extension and then rename the file to .caf afterwards.  We need the .caf extension since the file may sync with iOS devices.